# Need to add all the integers between 2 other integers

Tags: python-3.x, integer

This is as far as i have gotten and dont know where go on from here.

```
result = 0
x = int(input('First: '))
y = int(input('Last: '))
y = y+1
for i in range((print(x+1, y)):
print(result)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your question refers to adding integers - are you literally trying to sum integers? Sample input and output might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second integer: "))

sumNum1Num2N = 0

print("Let's sum all the integers in this range [%d, %d]" %(num1, num2))

#This shows up the sum being done
for i in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        sumNum1Num2N = sumNum1Num2N + i
        print(sumNum1Num2N, " " , end="")

print()
print("The sum of the numbers between %d and %d is %d" %(num1, num2, sumNum1Num2N))
```

If you want to show the integers between 2 numbers.

```
for i in range(num1, num2 + 1):
        print(i)
```

But if you want a fastest way to sum 2 numbers use the built-in functions `sum` and `range`:

```
m_sum = sum(range(num1, num2 + 1)) #[num1, num2]
```

Mathematically you can achieve also the sum of the numbers between A and B, where B > A:

```
B*(B + 1)/2 - (A - 1)*A/2

= (B^2 + B - A^2 + A) / 2

= ((B - A)*(B + A) + (B + A)) / 2

= (B + A) * (B - A + 1) / 2
```

But I think this is more complicated than the other 2 methods, even though the mathematical procedure is trivial ;)

Comment: Do not use eval. The OP's use of int is safer. It's also unnecessary to iterate to sum a range of integers.

Comment: I did it cause the OP wants to see the sum being done!!! See its comment on the other answer to confirm what I am saying.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Ok, changed eval for int ;)

Comment: I think it's better to use xrange too.

Comment: Add in the use of the formula (x + y)*(y - x +1)/2 to short circuit if there's no need to see the sum built and I will up vote - avoiding iterations for basic math seems worth emphasizing, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I disagree that the formula is more complicated, at least if you don't need to run through the proof, but I will stand by my up vote promise - and it's probably good to show the variety of options.

Comment: I think that the usage of 2 built-in functions such as **range** and **sum** it's easier first of all to somebody who is new to programming than the mathematical procedure to achieve it

Comment: To me it feels like an example implementing, say, multiplication through repeated addition - useful to demonstrate what's going on but not actually what you'd want to do in practice. But I'm probably just splitting hairs.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Youre probably right, 'cause I am quite stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
x = int(input('First: '))
y = int(input('Last: '))
for i in range(x,y+1):
    print(i)
```

Comment: It almost does it, i also cant figure out hot to get all of the numbers printed to add up and then give the answer to it

eg
first: 1
last: 7
1
3
6
10
15
21
28

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> x = int(input('First: '))
First: 1
>>> y = int(input('Last: '))
Last: 10
>>> print(' + '.join(str(e) for e in range(x+1,y)),'=',sum(range(x+1,y)))
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 44
```